# Solr not matching. Threshold setting, or something weird?

Tags: search, solr, solandra

I'm using solr to search for articles. I created 2 test "body" sentences which have the common word "tall", but there is no match.

The Query---> Body:"There are tall people outside" AND !UserId:2

**Does not match a post with:**

Body: the KU tower is really tall
UserId:3

Is this just simply a very low matching score? or is there something else going on here? In the case of a low matching score should it really be that low? The body sentences are very short and share a common word, I would have expected some match.

**EDIT**: I think the matching isn't happening as a result of having the  !UserId: 2 condition. If I try to match body sentences without that, its very liberal. Can anyone explain this? and perhaps how to best structure a query to avoid this type of specific behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come after me, I found a solution however not necessarily an explanation for its behavior.

The Solr query:

```
(PostBody:There are tall people outside) AND !UserId:2
```

worked as I desired above. Note that if the quotes are added around the body, it does not match. I believe Solr attempts to match such a query as a single string rather than individual words.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some funky behavior with the ! operator with Solr. I would suggest you use the - (negative indicator) instead as shown in the [SolrQuerySyntax Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax). Try changing your original query to `Body:"There are tall people outside" AND -UserId:2` to see if that works as you are expecting.

Comment: Negative. Same behavior I believe.